# What is the right way to use "instanceof"?

Tags: php, symfony

I have this code:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($entities as $entity)
{
    $person = $entity->getPerson();

    echo "Iteration: " . $i . " Person Type: " . get_class($person);

    if ($person instanceof NaturalPerson)
    {
        $id = $person->getIdentificationType() . $person->getCI();
    }
    else
    {
        $id = $person->getIdentificationType() . $person->getRIF();
    }

    $i++;
    $order['id'] = $id;

    $orders[] = $order;
}
```

But any time I run the function I get this error:

> Attempted to call method "getRIF" on class
>   "Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson" in
>   /var/www/html/tanane/src/Tanane/BackendBundle/Controller/OrderController.php
>   line 114. Did you mean to call: "getCI", "getId"?

And I don't know why since the `echo` at first lines return this:

```
Iteration: 0 Person Type: Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\LegalPerson
Iteration: 1 Person Type: Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson
```

Why is that? Where is the error?

Comment: This happens when you call deprecated methods in Symfony. You should convert your code to call the replacement method.

Comment: @Barmar `deprecated methods`? What you mean with that? Which method is deprecated in my code? The error stated here is that `instanceof`, which is a PHP function BTW, is not working right, that's my problem

Comment: It's telling you that `getRIF` is deprecated, and you should switch to either `getCI` or `getId`. Where do you see anything about `instanceof` in the error message?

Comment: I'm not a Symfony users, so maybe my interpretation of the other questions with that error message are wrong, so I've reopened.

Comment: @Barmar this is because `getRIF` belongs to `LegalPerson` entity and `getCI` belongs to `NaturalPerson`

Comment: I see what you're saying. Maybe you need to qualify the class name, `instanceof Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson`

Comment: @Barmar that was the problem I complety forgot to include the `use` statement, can you answer the question in order to give you the points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either check against the Fully Qualified Class Name (FQCN):

```
if ($person instanceof \Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson)
```

Or you need to place a USE statement at the top of your file (below your namespace):

```
use Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson;
```

All Symfony classes are namespaced, so PHP won't be able to find a class "NaturalPerson" if it doesn't exist within the same namespace as the file that's calling it.

[PHP Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)